# How to run the following Oracle exec statements in SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have came across these statements which are supposed to be run in Oracle, however I am not sure how these statements should be run.  Tried running them as SQL but doesn't work.

```
variable output1 NUMBER;
variable output2 VARCHAR2(100);

exec rp_orader_closure_pxkg.rp_exaec_close_SILvl_WKO('aaa',
                                                     '1',
                                                     '10aaa001a6414339',
                                                     :output1, :output2);
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Any messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure all the SQLPlus commands work in SQL Developer. You can certainly do that in an anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
    output1 NUMBER;
    output2 VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    rp_orader_closure_pxkg.rp_exaec_close_SILvl_WKO('aaa', '1', 
        '10aaa001a6414339', output1, output2);
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me, SQL Developer v3.0.04. In the script window, I enter:

```
create or replace package p as
procedure prc (p1 in varchar2, p2 in out varchar2);
end;
/
create or replace package body p as
procedure prc (p1 in varchar2, p2 in out varchar2) is
begin
  p2 := p1;
end prc;
end;
/
variable output2 VARCHAR2(100);

exec p.prc('aaa',:output2);

print output2;
```

In the script output window:

```
PACKAGE p compiled
PACKAGE BODY p compiled
anonymous block completed
OUTPUT2
---
aaa
```

Perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Just lose the first two lines and execute only the line with `exec` at the beginning. SQL developer will ask you for the values of the variables. Just leave them `NULL`, as they are output parameters.